# Attach image base64 coded in a mail with cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, email, phonegap-plugins

I use this code to open mail and pass data:

```
function mail(Segnalazioni) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // window.plugin.email is now available
}, false);

window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable(
    function (isAvailable) {
        // alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable;
    }
);

window.plugin.email.open({
    to:      ['m****.s*****@****.com'],
    cc:      [],
    bcc:     [],
    subject: 'Greetings',
    body:    '<img src="'+ Segnalazioni.FotoCamera +'">',
    isHtml:  true
});

window.plugin.email.open(properties, function () {
    console.log('email view dismissed');
}, this);

};
```

but the result on the device is that the mail find in the body only an object.

if i send the mail the result is an empty body mail.

the result is this:
[image]

Comment: Is your base64 data prefixed with `data:image/png;base64,` ?

Comment: yes, i tried even with jpeg but nothing changed

Comment: From the plugin docs under known issues: `<img> tags do not work on Android.` It looks like this might not work.

Comment: so, there is another way to overcome the problem?